# Replace line in php file with sed from bash

Tags: bash, replace, sed

I try to replace some text in a file with the command **sed** from **bash**

I want to replace the line :

```
$app["gentle.root"] = "/home/doc/";
```

to

```
$app["gentle.root"] = "/home/exemple/";
```

I try :

```
sed -i's/$app["gentle.root"] = "/home/doc/";/$app["gentle.root"] = "/home/exemple/";' /home/martialp/Documents/default.php
```

But I'm getting this error

```
sed: -e expression n°1, caractère 7: commande inconnue: `m'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should escape spcial symbols:

```
sed -i 's/\$app\[\"gentle.root\"\] = \"\/home\/doc\/\"\;/\$app\[\"gentle.root\"] = \"\/home\/exemple\/\"\;/'  /home/martialp/Documents/default.php
```

Comment: or you can avoid having to escape N number of `/` chars, by using an alternate substitute/replace field delimiter, like `s@1/string@2/string'` Some seds require being "notified" that you're deliberatly using an alternate delim, and you have to do `s\@1/string@2/string@'` Good luck to all.

Answer (score 0):

Think from another way, and recommend to use other Character if the replace line has "/" in it.

```
sed '/gentle.root/ s#/home/doc#/home/exemple#' file
```